# issue redis and docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis

I currently have a very strange error with docker more precisely with redis.

**My backend runs with nodejs and typescript:**

> code

```
const redisPubSubOptions: any = {
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || "127.0.0.1",
  port: process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379,
  connectTimeout: 10000,
  retryStrategy: (times: any) => Math.min(times * 50, 2000),
};

export const pubsub: RedisPubSub = new RedisPubSub({
  publisher: new Redis(redisPubSubOptions),
  subscriber: new Redis(redisPubSubOptions),
});
```

> Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine as tsc-builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .
RUN yarn install

EXPOSE 4000

CMD yarn run dev
```

> docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  
  backend:
    build: .
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - 4242:4242
    depends_on:
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./docker/env/.env.dev
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=development
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - REDIS_HOST=redis

  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.12-alpine
    command: redis-server --maxclients 100000 --appendonly yes
    hostname: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    restart: always
```

when I start my server the backend works and then the redis error comes after:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Comment: Is something else in your code trying to connect to Redis?  Or, is `REDIS_HOST` also set in the `.env.dev` file?  If you modify your code to just print out the value of `process.env.REDIS_HOST`, what does it show?  I'd expect the code you've included here to work.

Answer (score 0):

Both Redis and your backend run on different containers, so they have different IP addresses in the docker network. You are trying to connect to `127.0.0.1`, which is the local address of the backend container.

**Method 1:**

Since you are using `docker-compose` (and of course it creates a network between services), you can use the service name instead of `127.0.0.1`. For example:

```
const redisPubSubOptions: any = {
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || "redis",
  port: process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379,
  connectTimeout: 10000,
  retryStrategy: (times: any) => Math.min(times * 50, 2000),
};

export const pubsub: RedisPubSub = new RedisPubSub({
  publisher: new Redis(redisPubSubOptions),
  subscriber: new Redis(redisPubSubOptions),
});
```

**Method 2:**

The other method is to expose the Redis port to the IP address of the Docker interface in the **Host machine**. Most of the time that is `172.17.0.1`, but with `ip -o a` (If you are using Linux) you can see the Docker interface and its IP address.
so you need to do this for that:

```
  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.12-alpine
    command: redis-server --maxclients 100000 --appendonly yes
    hostname: redis
    ports:
      - "172.17.0.1:6379:6379"
    restart: always
```

This address 172.17.0.1:6379 (Or any Docker interface IP address on the Host) should be exposed for Redis. Easily you can use this address in the application.

**Note:** You can handle these values using environment variable which is a better and more standard solution. You can take a look [at this](https://12factor.net/config).

Comment: Since the original code uses `process.env.REDIS_HOST` as its first choice, I'd expect the setting `environment: [REDIS_HOST=redis]` to work, without modifying the code at all.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for mentioning that. I didn't pay attention to that.